# Looking for a working Hauppauge Colossus filter graph

Tags: c++, directshow, capture

I'm really having no luck in getting my Hauppauge Colossus to work in my app. Does anyone have a working filter graph for this device? Or a c++/c# list of filters that need to be added to a filter graph in order to view a Component source?

Answer:

So I finally got the it figured out, the answer to my not-a-question. If anyone is looking for the same thing, the filter graph looks like this:

- Hauppauge Colossus Crossbar
- Hauppauge Colossus Capture
- Hauppauge Colossus TSEncoder
- Hauppauge Graph Utility Filter (Microsoft Demux)
- Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder
- Microsoft DTV-DVD Audio Decoder
- Video Renderer
- Audio Renderer

Comment: You can try to create a running filtergraph in GraphEdit or GraphStudioNext first. I have a Haupage USB Converter where I needed to insert the CrossBar filter for the source. Maybe this is missing.

Comment: `ICaptureGraphBuilder2` inserts and connects the CrossBar filter if necessary when you call `ICaptureGraphBuilder2::FindInterface(IAMCrossbar)` on the source filter.